# OSX 10.11 enable ssh diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Tags: macos, ssh

Since we updated our mac from 10.10 to 10.11 our tomcat can't connect anymore with the error

```
[SSH] Exception:Algorithm negotiation fail
```

This answer shows that we have to anable the diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 again:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424621/algorithm-negotiation-fail-ssh-in-jenkins

i tried

```
sudo vi /private/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and added a line, because there was no line starting with "Ciphers"

```
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openss.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

but after restaring the daemon

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd; sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd;
```

i can't connect at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This answer shows that we have to anable the diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424621/algorithm-negotiation-fail-ssh-in-jenkins

`diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` is not cipher, but key exchange algorithm. You need to allow it such as:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

The line `Ciphers [...] diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` is invalid and it prevents your server to start.

Comment: thanks, i tried that, but now i get: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: what openssh version do you have? What do you see in system log related to sshd?

Comment: OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8 - sshd[5542]: fatal: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 36: Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms '+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'.

Comment: So then you need to write full list with older versions

Comment: that's it, i've added the line from the stack-overflow answer: KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1