# OSX 10.11 Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms '+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, git, openssh

I have updated my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file based on the answers provided here -
[OSX 10.11 enable ssh diffie-hellman-group1-sha1](https://superuser.com/questions/1051570/osx-10-11-enable-ssh-diffie-hellman-group1-sha1)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424621/algorithm-negotiation-fail-ssh-in-jenkins

```
# Ciphers and keying   
Ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com  

#RekeyLimit default none  
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

And restarted the SSHD daemeon using these commands:

```
sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist  
sudo launchctl load -w  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

But still I am getting the same error:

```
id$ git clone ssh://<user>@<host>:<port>/<repo>
Cloning into 'xxxxx'...
Unsupported KEX algorithm "+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"
/Users/<user>/.ssh/config line 2: Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms '+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I am on OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you might also want to double-check the contents of the `/Users/<user>/.ssh/config` client config file; I suspect that the culprit may lie there, not in the server-side config files.

Answer (score 3):

This feature (the `+` sign) is supported [from openssh 7.0](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html):

If you need to use this specific algorithm, you need to specify it directly in `~/.ssh/config`, such as

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Comment: `Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms '+` here because OpenSSH previous v7 does not "understand" the '+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1' syntax you used. I have that too with a Debian Jessie server. You can cure this by listing your **server** supported ciphers  with `ssh -Q cipher`, copy/paste the result in `sshd_config`, then adding your wanted cipher. E.g `Ciphers  chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, (...),diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`. Note I've put no "+".

Comment: that is precisely what I wrote in this answer.

Comment: You pint pointed cause of OP's issue ; I explain how to cure it on the *server* side.

Comment: @tuk0z The `ssh -Q cipher` lists **client** supported ciphers. The `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` is not a cipher, but **key exchange algorithm**. Doing as you wrote, would prevent your sshd server from starting, because it is invalid value for `ciphers`.

Comment: Yes. So with OpenSSH previous v7 we need to add any supported Key exchange algorithm using the old syntax, e.g. `KexAlgorithms [default Kex],diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` that is without the `+`  in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. My bad for mixing Cipher and Kex in my previous comment and thank you @jakuje for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

### Adding a login with options to .ssh/config on Mac OS X

I had a similar issue on Mac OS X 12.4 Monterey when logging in to an old Ubuntu server via SSH, so after reading this (and many other pages) and noting what the server offered on unsuccessful attempts, I tried adding the lines to my SSH config file as suggested above, but without success.

Then I tried logging in using the specific command and the first of three algorithms offered by the old server:

`ssh -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 root@MYSERVERIP`

(obviously replacing the latter with my servers IP address) which was successful.

Then because I use other SSH quick logins I added the following in "~/.ssh/config":

```
Host PETNAME
  HostName MYSERVERIP
  User root
  port 22
  KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

where "PETNAME" is a memorable name I allocated to the server, and "root" is the user - obviously this could be another username on the server.

I can now connect with `ssh PETNAME` on the command line (entering the password after the prompt).